# Create Back Button in Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

I am trying to create a back button in Joomla menus

here is my javascript code

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery(".asset-main-menu a[title='Back']").click(function()
    {window.history.back();});

});
```

I've added "back" to the link Title Attribute

but it doesnt seem to work

anything im doing wrong?

Comment: Step one. Open the chrome developer console. Look to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Hi, checked console, no errors pertaining to this issue,

Comment: It's really hard to troubleshoot as this isn't a [MCVE]

Comment: thanks for the reply, i understand that, apart from adding the html, there isnt much else to add. but is it the correct javascript function?

Comment: Browsers already come with back buttons.

Answer (score 0):

just so this can be closed off

i found the issue

which was, the url of the menu item was executing before the javascript

so changing it to this

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery(".asset-main-menu li a[title='Back']").click(function(event) 
{event.preventDefault();window.history.back();});
});
```

This prevents the default click event from being propagated and allowing the javascript to execute.